# Gtk Notebook widget adding new tabs error

Tags: c++, widget, gtk, gtk3

I have this `newTab()` function that is creating a `Notebook` widget on first run, should create new pages for the next iterations(calls).

It works for the first run, i.e create a notebook with a new tab labeled "Document". But on the next call, it creates a tab but the DrawingArea is not created. I can't even toggle through these new tabs.

I get the error: `Gtk-WARNING **: Can't set a parent on widget which has a parent`

My code is:

```
void myclass:: newTab()
{
if(!checkFlag)
{
    drawpointer = new DrawingArea();
    drawArea = drawpointer->createArea();
    View = GTK_NOTEBOOK(gtk_notebook_new());
    gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (View, GTK_POS_TOP);
    label = gtk_label_new ("Document");
    gtk_notebook_append_page (View, drawArea, label);
    gtk_box_pack_start(box, GTK_WIDGET(View), TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_box_reorder_child (box, GTK_WIDGET(View), 1);
    gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(View));
    checkFlag = true;
  }
    label = gtk_label_new ("Document1");
    cPage = gtk_notebook_get_current_page (View);
    gtk_notebook_insert_page (View, drawArea, label, cPage + 1);
    gtk_notebook_next_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK (View));   
  }
```

This is my `DrawingArea` class

```
DrawingArea:: DrawingArea()
{
}

GtkWidget* DrawingArea::createArea()
{
drawingArea = gtk_drawing_area_new();
gtk_widget_show (drawingArea);
return drawingArea;
}
```

I think this is the problem for calling the same drawingarea widget that has already been created. But I don't know understand how I should resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting help from IRC, I deduced that whenever 2nd time the `newTab()` is called, same `drawingArea` widget was being added to the new tab which results in the error.

This was resolved by taking out the drawpointer out of the if block as following:

```
void myclass:: newTab()
{
  drawpointer = new DrawingArea();
  drawArea = drawpointer->createArea();
if(!checkFlag)
{  
  View = GTK_NOTEBOOK(gtk_notebook_new());
  gtk_notebook_set_tab_pos (View, GTK_POS_TOP);
//label = gtk_label_new ("Document");
//gtk_notebook_append_page (View, drawArea, label);
  gtk_box_pack_start(box, GTK_WIDGET(View), TRUE, TRUE, 0);
  gtk_box_reorder_child (box, GTK_WIDGET(View), 1);
  gtk_widget_show (GTK_WIDGET(View));
  checkFlag = true;
}
  label = gtk_label_new ("Document1");
  cPage = gtk_notebook_get_current_page (View);
  gtk_notebook_insert_page (View, drawArea, label, cPage + 1);
  gtk_notebook_next_page (GTK_NOTEBOOK (View));   
}
```

This results in creating a new drawing widget everytime the `newTab()` is called.
I hope this helps someone else as well.